# Naming after two people

Tags: names

Can one person be given *one* name (as opposed to a double name) which is meant to "correspond" to two different deceased individuals?

I.e. Chaim and Shprintza have a daughter.  Chaim's grandmother was named Genendel and Shprintza's grandmother was named Genendel.  Can their daughter be named Genendel after both?

I am asking if this "works" to whatever extent naming after someone "works."  I am not asking if it is allowed, because I assume that there is no reason it wouldn't be allowed.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23121/naming-a-child-after-two-relatives

Comment: Reminds me of the Chelm story of a husband and wife having the same argument. Answer, name the baby and see which one she resembles as she grows up. I once saw a comment from Rabbi Avigdor Miller, just don't tell the relatives which one and let them think what they want. The case was naming a baby after a tzadik and letting the relatives think it was after someone on "their" side.

Comment: @sabbahillel If you can source your R' Miller comment, it would be evidence that he held it doesn't "work"